# Converting ActiveRecord results to json in transaction script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, rspec

I've seen a number of posts on this but none of the solutions seem to be working for this application.  I have a transaction script, CreateContact, which returns a success object when added to the database:

```
class CreateContact < TransactionScript
  def run(params)
    contact = Contact.create(params)
    return success(contact: contact)
  end
end
```

Here's my test code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CreateContact do

  it_behaves_like('TransactionScripts')
  let(:script) {CreateContact.new}

  it "creates a contact" do
    contact = CreateContact.run({:name=>'contact1', :email=>'me@email.com', :phoneNum=>'1234567'})
    expect(contact.success?).to eq(true)
    expect(contact.name).to eq('contact1')
    expect(contact.email).to eq('me@email.com')
    expect(contact.phoneNum).to eq('1234567')
  end
end
```

I've tried several ways of parsing to a hash or JSON: splitting apart the params hash in Contact.create, adding ".to_json" and "JSON.parse" to the success object value, calling both on the entire success object, and calling '.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)'.  I've also tried converting the test code properties between the '.property', '[:key]', and '['property']' formats.  '['property']' is the only one that seems to return anything, but it only returns "property" (instead of a value).

When running the tests I can actually see that the ActiveRecord object is created successfully, and some of these techniques will parse if I call them in binding.pry, but when I try to implement them in the code the tests still turn up nil values.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To convert an ActiveRecord object to a JSON-like Hash, you can use the `as_json` method from the [Active Model JSON Serializer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html):

```
hash = contact.as_json
#=> {"id"=>1, "name"=>"contact1", ...}
```

You can then access the contents of the hash with `hash["attribute"]`. However, you will *not* be able to call `hash[:attribute]` or `hash.attribute`:

```
hash["name"]   #=> "contact1"
hash[:name]    #=> nil
hash.name      #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for {}:Hash
```

If you want to add that behavior to the hash you can build an [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) from the hash:

```
hash2 = OpenStruct.new(contact.as_json)

hash2["name"]  #=> "contact1"
hash2[:name]   #=> "contact1"
hash.name      #=> "contact1"
```

If you just need the JSON as an actual `String`, use `to_json`:

```
json = contact.to_json
#=> "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"contact1\",...}"
```